# Windows Server Alternative Sign In

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012

In the organization I work for, some users are often in a position where they cannot access their workstations when an administrator needs to do something on their user account or when they need to send someone else a file that's on their desktop.

Is there any way that I can designate a user / a password that can be used to sign into any user account in a specific group? Right now we have to ask for the user's password, which is both unprofessional and immoral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way that I can designate a user / a password that can be used to sign into any user account in a specific group?

No. There is not.

---

There is no was to log in as a user with credentials other than their own. There are a couple of ways to handle this.

1. Reset their password, log in and do your stuff, reset it again and leave them a sticky note with the new password and force them to change it on logon.
2. Log in with a different account and do the configuration. If you need to do something in that user's profile, then this won't work, but it will for general configuration issues.
3. Standardize changes across your organization using Group Policy and/or SCCM. This way the only time you need to log in to a user's account on their behalf is for break/fix incidents, not for general configuration.

Some combination of these three things should get you what you want while leaving behind a proper audit trail.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of a way to authenticate as another user without their password. When I find myself in a situation where I need to grab an item off of another users desktop, or a similar situation this is how I do it:

1. In the Active Directory Users and Computers program, locate one of the admin accounts that should be able to access multiple workstations and select it.
2. Under the account tab, click the "Log on to" button.
3. Depending on your setup, you can leave the radio button at "All computers" or you can specify which workstations they can log in to by listing the host names.

From there your admins should be able to go to any workstation you specify they can access, log un using DOMAIN\Username, and navigate to the local user profile "c:\Users\%username%" to access any files you might need from there.

Of course your configuration might be completely different so I apologize if this does not apply to you.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "needs to do something"? There is no such thing.
Seems like you have an Active Directory, so everything is handled with Active Directory. If you need to test something, create a testuser which is in the same groups/applies the same policies which you want to test. If it works with the testuser it will work with other users in the same group/with same policies. Disable this account if you have finished testing.

Comment: This kind of request is common for fixing a user issue where, say, their Outlook profile is doing weird things. You need to log into that specific computer under that specific user account to see and fix the issue. I agree that standardization thought GPO is important, but there are plenty of legitimate circumstances where it would be good to be logged in as an existing user to troubleshoot certain things.